# Using subprocess - how to specify working directory in remote server

Tags: python-2.7, unix, server, subprocess

I'm trying to use Python's subprocess module to connect to a remote server via Putty and download files from it.
The files are not located in the root or home directory.

Heres a summary of my issues:
The below code will run and list all files in the home directory of the client server:

```
import sys,subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','username@hostip', 'ls -a'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()
out.decode("utd-8").split('\n')[:-1]
print(out)
print(err)
```

My aim is to go to a child folder in the home like home/child/child2, I tried using cd in the argument between 'ssh' and 'ls', this will compile but return nothing even though there are files in there.

```
import sys,subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','username@hostip', 'cd home/child/child2', 'ls -a'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()
out.decode("utd-8").split('\n')[:-1]
print(out)
print(err)
```

I've also tried to take out the 'cd' and place a 'cwd' in the Popen argument list as so

```
import sys,subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','username@hostip', 'ls -a'], cwd = 'child/child2/', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()
out.decode("utd-8").split('\n')[:-1]
print(out)
print(err)
```

but the program will return
`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'child/child2/'`

What is the correct way to do this? I'm limited to Python 2 and using the subprocess module.

Comment: `"utd-8"` is not a valid encoding name; presumably you mean `"utf-8"`

Comment: Putty is a Windows client, but all your code here looks like you are actually on a Unix-like platform (the Putty client `plink.exe` does something similar on Windows). If you really want to do this from Windows, probably clarify this ... or rather, probably edit this question to remove the odd Windows language and ask a new question specifically about how to do this with `plink`

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `ssh` should be a single string with the shell script command(s) to execute on the remote server.

The immediate problem with your attempt is that the second and subsequent arguments are simply ignored by most `cd` implementations.

Python in general and `subprocess` in particular obviously have no idea what `ssh` does or any control over what happens on the other side of the remote connection (though you could explore the [paramiko third-party library](https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/) if you want that sort of thing in Python).

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['ssh','username@hostip', 'cd home/child/child2; ls -a'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

For running a single command and waiting for it to complete, you should probably prefer `subprocess.check_output`;

```
output = subprocess.check_call(
    ['ssh','username@hostip', 'cd home/child/child2; ls -a'])
```

This does not easily give you access to any error messages, though. Python 3.5+ has `subprocess.run` which gives you more versatile options. You really should be thinking about abandoning Python 2 anyway.

```
# Python 3.5+
result = subprocess.run(
    ['ssh','username@hostip', 'cd home/child/child2; ls -a'],
    text=True, check=True)
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```

Another option for complex shell scripts is to provide them as standard input to the `ssh` command.

```
# Python 3.5+
commands = """\
cd home/child/child2
ls -a"""
result = subprocess.run(
    ['ssh','username@hostip'],
    text=True, check=True, input=commands)
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```